# How to map knowledge statements/relationships from text file to (directed) graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, directed-graph

I have the following Data in a .txt file, I need to map it to a graph but I have no real idea how to do that? I mean the formatting. I am not allowed to change the data in the file, but I need to map the vertices/edges but I do not know how to take a part of a string(from a line in a text file) And then map the edge to the end of that string? if that makes sense?

This is the text file in question

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
Trout is-a fish
Fish has gills
Fish has fins
Fish is food
Fish is-an animal
Apple is-a fruit
Fruit has stem
Fruit is food
Fruit is-a vegetable
Animal is-a living-thing
Vegetable is-a living-thing
Cod is-a fish
Trout lives-in freshwater
Cod lives-in saltwater
Tiger is-a cat
Tiger has stripes
Tiger is wild
Tabbie is-a cat
Tabbie has stripes
Tabbie is-a pet
Flag has stripes
Flag is-an artifact
Cat is-a mammal
Mammal is-an animal
Dog is-a mammal
```

Comment: [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))?

Comment: But how do you do that? say how would I say before is or is-an or has-a and then after?

Comment: probably you should start with simpler tasks, like string comparison, and only then try something with graph

Comment: You asked a too big question. Writing up some GUI that will show vertices and edges of a graph is not a 5 minute job that you can explain in a few words. Regarding some parts of your question -- you don't need to change Data.txt just load it in some data structure and manipulate it there. To make your question better you should provide a smaller Data.txt and an solution (as in graph) to your problem for that smaller Data.txt so people understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish and lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @Spidey thanks, I'm working on getting a smaller sample working, I'll be back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line, split on space.

```
String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");
```

You'll have the relation type in `lineParts[1]` for example. Then you can use parts 0 and 2 to build the graph in the datastructure you chose.

Comment: Right. Scanning the list, the verbs can all be replaced by either `∈` or `⊂` (well - roughly), and they all serve the same *function*. It'd be mildly more interesting if there was a single `∉` in there as well.